# Is there an equivalent to Java's :: notation referring to member functions?

Tags: c#

In Java I can write:

```
Comparator.comparing(Match::getDate)
.thenComparing(Match::hashCode)
.thenComparing ...
```

instead of having to write

```
Comparator.comparing(m -> m.getDate())
    .thenComparing(m -> m.hashCode())
    .thenComparing ...
```

Is there a similar shorthand in C# to refer to member functions as lambda expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, the `::` notation is called a method reference.  There is no direct equivalent to a method reference in C#, but the closest representation to that in C# is member groups, which allows you to simplify some lambda expressions that meet certain requirements.

This is a good read: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ConvertClosureToMethodGroup.html

Without method groups:

```
    private static int[] ParseInt(string s)
    {
        var t = ParseString(s);
        var i = t.Select(x => int.Parse(x));
        return i.ToArray();
    }
```

Using method groups:

```
    private static int[] ParseInt(string s)
    {
        var t = ParseString(s);
        var i = t.Select(int.Parse);
        return i.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Note that method groups do _not_ work for `Queryable` linq methods (e.g. in Linq-to-Entiites) since they are not implicitly convertible to expressions.